# How to customize to_json response in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, response, dry, respond-with

I am using `respond_with` and everything is hooked up right to get data correctly.  I want to customize the returned `json`, `xml` and `foobar` formats in a DRY way, but I cannot figure out how to do so using the limited `:only` and `:include`. These are great when the data is simple, but with complex finds, they fall short of what I want.

Lets say I have a post which `has_many` images

```
def show
  @post = Post.find params[:id]
  respond_with(@post)
end
```

I want to include the images with the response so I could do this:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find params[:id]
  respond_with(@post, :include => :images)
end
```

but I dont really want to send the entire image object along, just the url.  In addition to this, I really want to be able to do something like this as well (pseudocode):

```
def show
  @post = Post.find params[:id]
  respond_with(@post, :include => { :foo => @posts.each.really_cool_method } )
end

def index
  @post = Post.find params[:id]
  respond_with(@post, :include => { :foo => @post.really_cool_method } )
end
```

… but all in a DRY way.  In older rails projects, I have used XML builders to customize the output, but replicating it across json, xml, html whatever doesnt seem right. I have to imagine that the rails gurus put something in Rails 3 that I am not realizing for this type of behavior. Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not the rails 3 built-in way, but I found a great gem that is actively maintained on Rails 3: [acts_as_api](https://github.com/fabrik42/acts_as_api)

Answer (score 21):

You can override `as_json` in your model. 
Something like:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      attribute: self.attribute, # and so on for all you want to include
      images:    self.images,    # then do the same `as_json` method for Image
      foo:       self.really_cool_method
    }
  end
end
```

And Rails takes care of the rest when using `respond_with`. not entirely sure what `options` gets set to, but probably the options you give to `respond_with` (`:include`, `:only` and so on)

Comment: He wants to change as_json, as_xml, as_foobar all in one place.

Comment: `include` does not use `as_json`, this doesn't help.

Answer (score 8):

Probably too late, but I found a more DRY solution digging through the rails docs.  This works in my brief tests, but may need some tweaking:

```
# This method overrides the default by forcing an :only option to be limited to entries in our
# PUBLIC_FIELDS list
def serializable_hash(options = nil)
  options ||= {}
  options[:only] ||= []
  options[:only] += PUBLIC_FIELDS
  options[:only].uniq!
  super(options)
end
```

This basically allows you to have a list of fields that are allowed for your public API, and you cannot accidentally expose the whole object.  You can still expose specific fields manually, but by default your object is secure for .to_json, .to_xml, etc.

Comment: Actually, this should probably just default when :only isn't specified, otherwise it changes the intent of using :only.  Oh, well, still my point is the same.

Comment: Overriding serializable_hash worked better for me to add in some methods as attributes in Rails 3.2.8, thanks!