# Creating json from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, mapping

I'm converting model query results to json and send them to selection box with

```
MyModel.find(params[:id]).my_sub_models.map(&:attributes)
```

I'm displaying my_sub_model :name(s) in selection box. Thats ok.

Later i added a column(:label) to sub model and i want to display a combined text in selection box like :name-:label. So i created a method

```
def combined_name
    self.name + "-" + self.label
end
```

How can i add combine_name for each item into my json now?

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include any methods on the model, use :methods.

```
my_model.to_json(:methods => :combined_name)
# => {"id": 1, "name": "My Name", "label": "Label",
      "created_at": "2012/02/01", "combined_name": "My Name - Label"}
```

Reference: [API Doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json).

***Update:***

`to_json` method of ActiveRecord was deprecated after 2.3.8. You probably are using Rails 3. [A similar question was asked sometime back here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719041/how-to-customize-to-json-response-in-rails-3) and the responses might help you here. Especially about the gem [acts_as_api](https://github.com/fabrik42/acts_as_api). Do check.

Comment: Thank you for response. But your way didnt worked for me. it gives me a json array without my method output in it.

Comment: Well i figured it out with as_json(:methods => "compound_name"). But thank you for reference and tipping. Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried collect?

```
MyModel.find(params[:id]).my_sub_models.collect { |sub_model| [ submodel.id, submodel.combined_name ] }
```

This way you will send only id and the name, that you will need for your select box.

Comment: Thank you for response,your way is working. But it gives me an array. I was using **option.name** for re-populating select box. With your way it will be like option[2]. First case is more readable. But if there isnt better solution, i will accept your answer:)

Comment: Thats not a problem, u could return a hash too. is just the way i writed it. u could do something like: collect { |sub_model| { :id => submodel.id, :name => submodel.combined_name }